# Visual Studio 2012 Template Set Custom Start Options

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

Ok so I am creating a Node.js Template in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. I have the Project that I will use as a template completely setup with Intellisense, Syntax highlighting and the Start options set to start node and run the server.js file contained within the project.

Now what I have done is exported this project as a Template to use for more node.js projects to come. However I cannot seem to get the Custom Start Options to stick to the template, in that I have to set the Start Options individually for each and every project. However the rest of the template works flawlessly. While, the Start Options not being set automatically is not that  big of a deal. I just imagine I must be missing something as I know that these are set with other templates that I have used. I have researched the subject and cannot seem to find an answer.

I know that I can use custom properties to set namespaces and things like that, but for some reason I cannot get it to work with the Start Options. Any help would be kindly appreciated.

To be clear, I am wondering how to set custom Start options in a Visual Studio 2012 Project template.